# Problems installing mysql on debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, mysql

I have a :

```
user@Node:~$ uname -a
Linux Node 2.6.32-042stab092.1 #1 SMP Tue Jun 24 09:10:28 MSK 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

With a :

```
user@Node:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
7.6
```

and I am having problems installing mysql server from repos !

```
user@Node:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readkey-perl tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5022 kB of archives.
After this operation, 74.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Preconfiguring packages ...
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Configuring mysql-server-5.5
----------------------------

While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the MySQL administrative "root" user.

If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.

New password for the MySQL "root" user: 



Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user: 


Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 28029 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-common (from .../mysql-common_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:amd64.
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (from .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.021-1+b1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 28129 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Unpacking mysql-client (from .../mysql-client_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.38-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.021-1+b1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
140826  0:14:52 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140826  0:14:52 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140826  0:14:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140826  0:14:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140826  0:14:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140826  0:14:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140826  0:14:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140826  0:14:52  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
140826  0:14:55  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140826  0:14:55 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140826  0:14:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140826  0:14:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140826  0:14:55 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140826  0:14:55 [ERROR] Aborting

140826  0:14:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Configuring mysql-server-5.5
----------------------------

Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a 
communication problem with the MySQL server.

You should check the account's password after the package installation.

Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.

[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-client (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
```

re-installed and had the same problem:

```
Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a 
communication problem with the MySQL server.

You should check the account's password after the package installation.

Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.

[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-client (5.5.38-0+wheezy1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Are you entering the password when prompted? Is apt-get giving you the opportunity?

Comment: yes, it is (twice)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that the default configuration for newer versions of MySQL do not work inside of an OpenVZ container. After the failure you can try adding `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then run `dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've done what you've said, and this is what I've got as an output : http://pastebin.com/R5hc2ikh